# How to initialize listview with search filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

How do I initialize listview with filter . I tried the following and it doesn't remove what I entered previously in search field of listview.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#addLocations', function() {
    alert("in");
    $("citynames").listview();
    $("citynames").listview('refresh');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. The following lines do what I want.

```
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#addLocations', function() {
        $('input[data-type="search"]').val("");
        $("[data-type=search]").trigger("change");
    });
```